# I get the wrong Line error while using Sass in cygwin in Win 7, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, ruby, sass

When I get a compile error in Sass, the error gives me the wrong line number, making it very very hard to debug and see what's wrong. Thoughts?

Environment: 
Windows 7, 
Sass running under Cygwin
Using Sublime2 as my text editor

Thanks, 
Alfie

Comment: Why not post up the error you get and your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out...

Either change the Line ending in the file from Windows Line Ends to Unix Line Ends

You can also set a flag in the command that takes care of this..

I hope this helps

Comment: For those of you wondering how to fix this, this answer is correct, just lacking the instructions.  here it is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854575/how-to-configure-compass-to-generate-files-with-unix-line-endings-on-windows